# What other way to get goerli testnet ether

Tags: testnets, faucets, goerli

I tried to get goerli testnet ether, but I could only get 0.05 ether every day, which was not enough for me to test the contract. When I got it from the tap, I was prompted that my Twitter account registration date was less than one week. What should I do now